# How to add the "isSum" bar in Highchart Waterfall chart in R?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I followed [this](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html) website to make a waterfall chart in R using Highcharts. But I am unable to add the "isSum" bar in the end. On how to do in .js is easily available but not for R.

I also tried to add a column in the df in the end by the name "isSum" and inserted true/false (after adding the cumulative sum row in the end) but it didn't work. Tried to do "isSum=T" under `hc_series` option also but didn't work.

An example is below:

```r
df=data.frame(y=c(232,345,544,100),name=c("one","two","three","four"))    

highchart()%>%
  hc_chart(type="waterfall")%>%
  hc_add_series(df)
```

Output from above:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is not perfect because I am not an R programmer - maybe it can be done better.
I don't know how to define data to include isSum property in R, but I know how to do it in JavaScript.

I used JS() function in R that allows us to inject JavaScript code and I updated the last point this way:

```
library(highcharter)

df=data.frame(y=c(232,345,544,100),name=c("one","two","three","four"))    

highchart()%>%
  hc_chart(type="waterfall", events = list(load = JS("function () {
          this.series[0].points[3].update({
            isSum: true
          });
  }")))%>%
  hc_add_series(df)
```

---

**edit** I got it. You can define it in your data like this:

```
df=data.frame(y=c(232,345,544,100),name=c("one","two","three","four"),isSum=c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't know about the JS() function. Can be very handy. Actually I had tried the isSum column thing also (mentioned this in my question also). But idiotically, used text "true"/"false" instead of boolean. Thanks again.

Comment: how can i put in a different color IsSum column?

Comment: You can update the color of the point just the same as in the code in my answer: this.series[0].points[3].update({ isSum: true, color: 'red' });